# Collision or movement Bug (Unity 2D game dev)

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

At relatively high speed, the character in collisions goes inside BoxCollider and RigidBody2D

[Demo gif Download Link](https://filecloud.me/xd14hujtt3ne.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A transform in Unity moves an object (teleports it) rather than moving it. To move a dynamic object, use AddForce / Velocity vector.

Example with Velocity:

```
float speed = 2.0f;
Rigidbody2D rb;
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
rb.velocity += new Vector2(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
```

rb.velocity += new Vector2(speed * Time.deltaTime, **0f**);

**0f** is Y axis of player position

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `Collision Detection` of the `RigidBody` to `Continuous`.